# path to div with jquery

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I have found a solution to playing and pausing vimeo videos with custom buttons, but I have now placed the buttons in a seperate div called buttonHolder and I can't seem to get the correct pathway to get the buttons to work when in their own div.

I would really appreciate any help.

my html would be:

## Player 1

```
<div class="buttonHolder">               
    <img class="simple" id="api_play" src="test.jpg" />
                <img class="simple" id="api_pause" src="test.jpg" />
</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
           <div>
            <h1>Player 2</h1>
            <div class="api_output"></div>
            <iframe id="player_2" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/3718294?js_api=1&js_swf_id=player_2" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<div class="buttonHolder">
    <img class="simple" id="api_play" src="test.jpg" />
    <img class="simple" id="api_pause" src="test.jpg" />
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My jquery code was:

```
var VimeoEmbed = {};

        //Called on document ready
        VimeoEmbed.init = function(e)
        {
            //Listen to the load event for all the iframes on the page
            $('iframe').each(function(index, iframe){
                iframe.addEvent('onLoad', VimeoEmbed.vimeo_player_loaded);
            });
        };


        //EVENT CALLBACKS
        /*
         * Called when the player finishes loading. The JavaScript API is only available
         * after this event fires.
         *
         * @param player_id (String): ID of the iframe which has finished loading.
         */
        VimeoEmbed.vimeo_player_loaded = function(player_id)
        {
            $('#'+player_id).prev('.api_output').append('VimeoEmbed.vimeo_player_loaded ' + player_id+'<br/>');

            var loop = 0;
            var volume = 100;

            //Simple Buttons
            $('#'+player_id).nextAll('img.simple').bind('click', {'player_id': player_id}, function(e){
                var iframe = $('#'+e.data.player_id).get(0);
                iframe.api( $(e.target).attr('id'), null );
            });

            //API EVENT LISTENERS
            VimeoEmbed.setupAPIEventListeners($('#'+player_id).get(0));
        };


        //On document ready
        $(document).ready(VimeoEmbed.init);
```

I am thinking that the code that requires editing is the following but I have tried multiple solutions with no luck.

```
//Simple Buttons
            $('#'+player_id).nextAll('img.simple').bind('click', {'player_id': player_id}, function(e){
                var iframe = $('#'+e.data.player_id).get(0);
                iframe.api( $(e.target).attr('id'), null );
            });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a jsFiddle when you have this much code posted. Here's a start for you... http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/pnX3d/11/

Comment: Duplicate IDs are not allowed in HTML, you need to fix that.

Comment: OK I'll get on the js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Why use `$('#'+player_id).nextAll('img.simple')` to find the buttons? This will only select the second set of buttons.. and it's precariously dependent on page layout. Not good.

It would be simpler to use a specific class on the "player buttons", or the class on the DIV containing them..

```
// Simple Buttons
//
var buttonClass = 'playerButtons_'+player_id;
var buttons = $('.buttonHolder img.'+buttonClass);
console.log('bind player buttons', buttons);
//
buttons.bind( 'click', {'player_id': player_id}, function(e){
    var iframe = $('#'+e.data.player_id).get(0);
    var action = $(e.target).attr('id');           // FUTURE -- from data('action').
    console.log('player button', iframe, action);
    iframe.api( action, null);
});
```

Either of the two selectors for 'buttons' should do it -- the first one more concise, but pretty much equivalent to the second. Working by IDs & classes and, if necessary, descendant structure is more robust (and probably efficient) than depending on DOM ordering.

If you're not sure what's happening, log the value (`length` especially) of `buttons` and log the player ID, iframe, and "button action".

Best practice would also make your buttons `<button type='button'>` rather than just images, and not be using the same ID value. (Use a different attribute -- perhaps `name` since it's a control, or `data-action` if you want to go HTML 5.)

Comment: Sorry, would it be possible to give the example in context. I am deliberately using images. I have to attach/.bind the click action to the buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code and thoughts. However, the buttons now all start the same video. I am guessing that is why the $('#'+player_id) was there before?

Comment: Then you need to put the buttons (or buttons & video both, for simplicity) in a common element! Or give the buttons a playerId-derived unique class! All you have to do is clearly identify either a container/ or your buttons, and make a simple robust jQuery to find them. Use `console.log()` & your debugger to make sure it works, this is simple stuff.

Comment: I realise it may be simple but not to me sadly as my areas are css, php mysql. I am looking to possibly outsource this if you are interested.

Comment: Sure, if you'd still like some help drop me a line at twhitmore dot nz at gmail dot com & we can discuss.